# "Mage_XmlConnect" requires module "Mage_Weee"

Tags: magento-1.7, dependency

I wonder if anyone has any idea on how to fix the error below.

There has been an error processing your request
Module "Mage_XmlConnect" requires module "Mage_Weee".

Trace:

```
#0 /home/kokorugs/public_html/online-carpet-store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(849): Mage::throwException('Module "Mage_Xm...')
#1 /home/kokorugs/public_html/online-carpet-store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(812): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_sortModuleDepends(Array)
#2 /home/kokorugs/public_html/online-carpet-store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(315): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_loadDeclaredModules()
#3 /home/kokorugs/public_html/online-carpet-store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModules()
#4 /home/kokorugs/public_html/online-carpet-store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#5 /home/kokorugs/public_html/online-carpet-store/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 /home/kokorugs/public_html/online-carpet-store/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}
```

Comment: It sounds like you disabled Mage_Weee in the module's activation file.  What were you trying to do when this problem appeared?

Comment: I haven't done anything in a while and when I last touched it, everything was fine.  I have no idea how this happened.

Comment: should I restore the default files listed?

Comment: I would definitely restore the Mage_* files in app/etc/modules as a start.  There obviously could be something deeper down but making sure everything there is standard issue is a first step.  Any modules installed recently, especially ones that deal with taxes?

Comment: No, could my server have anything to do with it?

Comment: So, I remember now I installed a debug extention, and that must have done it.  I restored app/etc/modules and now I can access my store

Comment: @AndrewQuackenbos can you please write this as an answer?

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have Mage_Weee disabled in app/etc/modules.  Changing the XML in Mage_Weee.xml to `<active>true</active>`, or restoring the folder from default, should restore the dependency issue being thrown.